# Is array size irrelevant in java?

Tags: java, arrays

As per the below statement,

> An array of subclass may be assigned to an array of its superclass. An array of implementing class may be assigned to an array of its interface type. Size is irrelevant.

I wrote below sample code to check the behavior of size in array

```
interface I{}
class C implements I{}

/* dummy.java*/
public class dummy{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        C[] c = new C[6];
        I[] i = new I[2];
        c[0] = new C();
        c[1] = new C();
        c[2] = new C();
        c[3] = new C();
        c[4] = new C();
        c[5] = new C();
        i = c;
        System.out.println(i[5].getClass());
    }
}
```

When i say, `new C[6];`, an object `[null,null,null,null,null,null]` gets created of type `class [LC` and `c` points to this object. When i say, `new I[2];`, an object `[null,null]` gets created of type `class [LI` and `i` points to this object.

My question:

How interface array is working here, when i say `i[5]`, despite an object `[null, null]` being created after defining `new I[2]`? What exactly is happening when i say `i = c;`? Is size of array of interface `new I[2];` getting modified during assignment `i = c;`?

Comment: When you say `i = c;`, the original array of `new I[2]` is being discarded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What that quote is trying to say is that the size of an array is part of the object, ie. it is not part of the reference or the variable type.

In

```
i = c;
```

you are assigning a copy of the value of the reference held in `c` to `i`. That is, `i` will reference the same instance as `c`.

> Is size of array of interface new I[2]; getting modified during assignment i=c;?

No, that's the whole point. `i` and `c` are just variables. Variable assignment has no side effects.

Comment: Oh i got u, size of an array is part of the object. I got u.

Comment: so that is why we are able to say, `Object o = c;`. Because size does not matter and `class [LC` is subclass of `class Object`. Is that correct?

Comment: @overexchange Yes. The state is part of the object. It plays absolutely no part in reference assignment.

Comment: Just to reiterate, Most of the time people say, we can do, `Object o = c;`, because `arrays are objects` which is a bit vague point to me. I think,  we can do this because `class [LC` is a subclass of `class Object`. we can do, `Object oa[] = c;`, because array of subclass of type `class [LC` can be assigned to array of super class of type  `class [Ljava.lang.Object`

Comment: @overexchange Both of those statements are the same thing. `Object` is the supertype of all reference types. Array types are reference types. So `Object` is the supertype of every array type. Array instances are therefore considered objects. For all those reasons, an expression of some array type can be assigned to a variable of type `Object`.

Comment: why -1 to this question?

Comment: @overexchange I don't know. The close vote also doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: Is `length` field part of this `class [LC`? Is that the reason why we can say `c.length` where c is `C[] c = new C[6];`

Comment: @overexchange Yes, the `length` field is part of the dynamically created array class. Every array type has a `public final int length` field.

Answer (score 0):

When you set
`i=c`

You are setting i to point to the object created by c. Therefore, `i` will now point to `C[6];` < this array

So...
`i[1] = new I();`
`c[1]` will return a `I object`